# Run function after getting a password

Tags: php, passwords

We have script http://site.com/ourscript.php

**How to add something like "enter password" block on that page?**

Just some simple, maybe popup.

**Like**, we open the page in browser, we should type password, if its ok - function will run.

It has to be done only inside requested php file, `.htaccess` should not be used.

Thanks.

Comment: Given the history of your last few questions (in rapid fire), are you trying to build a bit of spyware (or other "hacking" tool) and hide it from the administrator?

Comment: @ircmaxell, nope, this is for demo (to show something for client). If you enter password - you will see, otherwise not.

Comment: Ok, just code obfuscation, php authenication, create new admin in WP, reading source code...  It appears kind of suspicious (I'm not saying you're up to no good, just it looks odd)...

Comment: @ircmaxell, new admin is for scam clients, who don't want to pay for work.

Comment: Just so you know, that's usually considered to be highly unethical and possibly even illegal (depending on where you are located).  A better option would be to not deliver the site to their server until you get payed.  So demo the site on your server where it's under your control, and then once you have payment (at least partial) you move to their server...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is about as simple as it gets:

```
<html>
    <body>

<?php if (isset($_POST['secret']) && $_POST['secret'] == "lolsecurity") { ?>

        <h1>Secret Page!</h1>
        <p>This type of password-protection is completely open to packet sniffing.</p>

<?php } else { ?>

        <form method="POST">
            <p>Enter Password:</p>
            <input type="password" name="secret">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>

<?php } ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [tutorial](http://www.codewalkers.com/c/a/Miscellaneous/Writing-a-Basic-Authentication-System-in-PHP/) for a basic authentication system. I'm sure if you spend two minutes googling, you'll find about a million pre-made, ready-to-go PHP login systems.

If you want to create your own, authenticating a user generally requires the following:

- First set up a users table in your database where you store valid usernames and their passwords (as well as any other pertinent user information). Passwords should not be stored in plain text, but should generally be *salted* and *hashed*.
- Add a login form to your application. When a user successfully logs in (which you can determine by taking the given password, salting and hashing it as above, and comparing it to the value in the database), use cookies or session to keep track of a login token.
- On each page requiring authentication, the login token should be verified. If an invalid login token or no login token is given, redirect to the login form.

Comment: Thanks man, any examples without using db? It would be perfect to have all the code inside one file.

Comment: You could hardcode usernames/passwords, I suppose, but that's hardly secure and I would never suggest doing that.